# Is there any way to read micr font characters from cheques using tesseract ocr or anyother package for python?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

When i used the pytesseract for character recognition on cheques, the micr characters are not getting recognized properly.

Comment: It would be easier for the community to answer your question when you share the sample program, the output and the error/exception you are getting.